# Angular How to make a multiple selection in a table

Tags: angular, database-design, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

I use Angular and bootstrap and I would like to be able to select multiple elements at the same time on a table. because I would like to use it to add more users at a time.

file.component.html

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="border: none;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="title-column">Id</td>
                <td class="title-column">Nom</td>
                <td class="title-column">Prenom</td>
                <td class="title-column">Rôle</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr *ngFor="let u of Utilisateur" (click)="setClickedRowList(u.id)" style="cursor: pointer;"
            [ngClass]="{'hvr-fade':!clickedList(u),'hvr-fade-selected': clickedList(u)}">
            <td class="row-left title">{{u.id}}</td>
            <td class="row-mid title">{{u.nom}}</td>
            <td class="row-mid title">{{u.prenom}}</td>
            <td *ngIf="u.admin==false" class="row-right"></td>
        </tr>
 </table>
```

file.component.ts

```
 selectedRowList: string;
 utilisateurRole: Role;
 selectedId: string;

 setClickedRowList(id: string) {
  this.selectedRowList = id;
}

 clickedList(index) {

  if(this.selectedRowList === index.id) {
   this.selectedId = index.id;

   this.utilisateurRole.admin = index.admin;

  return true;
  } else {
   return false;
  }

}
```

If not, if you know a method or I can check

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to keep track of which rows are selected. Here's a simple implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5k2kgl

I made it so the rows are selected / unselected when they're clicked. and the selected rows have a blue background color.

You can get the selected rows using the `getSelectedRows` method.

Comment: Thanks for that example, that was of great help! I forked and extended it to support multi-select with ctrl click and shift click, see
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n3xdqq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts