# Angular: Avoid browser selecting text on Shift-click

Tags: javascript, html, angular, browser

I have a table that a user can select single rows by clicking on them, multiple rows by Ctrl+clicking on them, and theoretically a user could select a range of rows by shift clicking another row - quite similar to what you would do when selecting multiple files in Windows explorer for example. That works just fine.

However, when shift-clicking to select multiple records from the table the browser (Chrome 103) will select the text in the table as illustrated below. The blue obviously is a selection the browser makes when shift clicking.

[image: My problem]

How can this be avoided?

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n3xdqq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Note: I extended an example I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59056496/angular-how-to-make-a-multiple-selection-in-a-table) and its [SB here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5k2kgl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to enable multiselect by shift click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)** css property to disable selection on table.

```
.table{
  user-select: none;
}
```

**[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkdr7z?file=src/app/app.component.css)**

Comment: That was terribly easy! Thanks, I did not know that functionality existed in CSS.